# Auto flush of tcp stream doesn't work

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, flush

As you may see I work a little SMTP server written in C#.
I included whole code (one class is not included), but I hope you get good view of detail.
I am struggeling at the DATA post from the client, the problem is in my point of view the not working "Auto Flush".
The client sends to my server "DATA" to tell me to get ready to receive data for my email.
I need to answer "354 start mail input", which I do, my problem is:
After sending "354 start mail input" I need to receive the message from client in this funtion.

```
 using System;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Sockets;
 using System.Threading;

namespace FakeSMTP
{
public class SMTPServer //: IDisposable
{
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream stream;
    System.IO.StreamReader reader;
    System.IO.StreamWriter writer;
    //public void Dispose()
    //{
    //    writer.Dispose();
    //    reader.Dispose();
    //    stream.Dispose();
    //}


    public SMTPServer(TcpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        stream = client.GetStream();
        reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 25);
        listener.Start();
        //using (SMTPServer handler = new SMTPServer(listener.AcceptTcpClient()))
        while (true)
        {
            SMTPServer handler = new SMTPServer(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
            Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(handler.Run));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {

        string sadress;
        string radress;
        string rserver;
        bool auth = false;
        writer.WriteLine("220 smtp.localsmtp.de ESMTP server ready");
        for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Read line {0}", line);

            if (line.StartsWith("EHLO"))
                {
                writer.WriteLine("250-smtp.localsmtp.de");
                //Auth ankuendigen
                writer.WriteLine("250 AUTH PLAIN");
                }

            if (line.StartsWith("QUIT"))
                {
                writer.WriteLine("221 Bye Sweetie see ya");
                client.Close();
                }

            #region auth

            if (line.StartsWith("AUTH PLAIN"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("client sendet Auth: " + line);
                string [] pw = line.Split(new string[] { "PLAIN " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pw[1]);
                string result = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytes);

                if (result == "12")
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("235 2.7.0 Authentication successful");
                        auth = true;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Falsche AUTH Daten");
                        writer.WriteLine("535 – Incorrect authentication data");

                    }
            }
                #endregion

            #region sender
            if (line.StartsWith("MAIL FROM") && auth == true)
                 {
                 string[] sadressa = line.Split(new string[] { "FROM:" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                 sadress = sadressa[1];
                 //Absender
                 sadress = sadress.Replace("<","").Replace(">","");
                 //Debug
                 Console.WriteLine("Absender: " + sadress);
                 writer.WriteLine("250 OK");
                 }

            #endregion

            #region receiver
            if (line.StartsWith("RCPT TO:") && auth == true)
                {
                    string[] radressa = line.Split(new string[] { "RCPT TO:" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    radress = radressa[1];
                    //Empfänger
                    radress = radress.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
                    if (samplesmtp.getMX.GetMXRecord(radress) != "invalid")
                    {
                        rserver = samplesmtp.getMX.GetMXRecord(radress);
                        Console.WriteLine("MX Record: " + rserver);
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ALARM");


                    //Debug
                    Console.WriteLine("Empfänger: " + radress);
                    writer.WriteLine("250 OK");
                }
            #endregion

            #region data

            if (line.StartsWith("DATA") && auth == true)
            {
               writer.WriteLine("354 start mail input");

               var emailLine = reader.ReadLine();
               while (!emailLine.Equals("."))
               {
                   // add emailLine to the email body
                   string[] emailbody = new string[] {emailLine};
                   Console.WriteLine("Emailbody: " + emailbody[0]); 
               }
               reader.Close();
               writer.Close();
               stream.Dispose();
               writer.WriteLine("250 OK");
            }

            #endregion

        }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to call .Flush() manually in code doesn't change the problem at all. No effect.

Comment: Your class needs to implement `IDisposable` as it holds quite a number of objects which implement `IDisposable` as well (i.e. all of its members).

Comment: How to use the .Dispose Methode in my context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your actual question you want to read all the lines until you receive a . on a line on it's own (see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), something like this: -

```
var emailLine = reader.ReadLine();
while (!emailLine.Equals("."))
{
   // add emailLine to the email body
   emailLine = reader.readLine();
}
writer.WriteLine("250 OK");
reader.Close();
writer.Close();
stream.Dispose();
```

Comment: No, I don't want edit my whole code. My problem is: After the client told me "DATA" I answer with ""354 start mail input". Now the client would sent me the whole email body, but this should be in the if statement above (in the `if (line.StartsWith("DATA") && auth == true)` block. As I told above the value of `line` doesn't change in this internal if block. I need to make the stream to be flushed/deleted between the two if blocks.

Comment: I was suggesting you put this code between the two if blocks, sorry if that wasn't clear. Your sample code doesn't actually read any lines between the two if blocks so that's probably the root of your problem.  After writing your 354 message and checking the value of line again

Comment: I edited code above, you mean using the code like this, or should I add another if statement into the while loop? Code seems to be an endless loop at the moment.

Comment: Sorry I made the same mistake as you in your original, and have corrected it now (after each line is processed I forgot to read the next one).

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot. Great to have some users like you here on stackoverflow. Nice day.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment to mine:

```
public class SMTPServer : IDisposable
{
    // all the other stuff

    public void Dispose()
    {
        writer.Dispose();
        reader.Dispose();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

calling code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 25);
    listener.Start();
    using (SMTPServer handler = new SMTPServer(listener.AcceptTcpClient()))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(handler.Run));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks, for answer Jesse. I edtited code in the first post. 
Using your solution doesn't work by me. Compiler told me after some time he can't access
the code 
`for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())`

because of it's locked by IDisposable. Any idea where I do wrong?

Comment: Um, what? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: I posted a new reply at the bottom of this page. I need to get the value of `line` flushed between the two internal if blocks (end of code, I used comments to show what I want to do in code).

Comment: I've edited my answer to show more concretely what you might do.

Comment: Seems like my problem is a bit difficult to describe. My problem is located in the "data" region. I check if the client told me "DATA", then I answer to this "DATA" command, now I need to write the data from client (done by using the var line). This value doesn't change since "DATA" and now. I think I need to find a way to flush the content of line and get the new value (whole email body which client sends) into value line. Hope you understand my problem. -Code above changed to your solution, no effect.